Sequence of actions

"When she comes we will be playing games"

It has two meanings I either start playing before and she enters when I'm in the middle of it or after her arrival we start playing together. It's just ambigous.

"When she came we were playing games"

Can we say the same about this sentence if not why?

Your first meaning for #1 (start playing) is perverse, and should be avoided by learners in favour of When she comes we will play games. But no such perverse interpretation is possble with #2 anyway. The "start playing" sense for the past is conveyed by When she came we played games. That's the same pattern as my corrected version of #1, so it should be easy enough to understand.

Part of the reason the "start playing" phrasing / interpretation for #1 is perverse is that even at time of speaking, "we will play games" is true - it doesn't become true only when she arrives. On the other hand, there's a case to be made for If she comes we will be playing games. But imho the continuous verb form there is dialectal / non-standard, so again it should be avoided by learners in favour of If she comes we will play games.

(Why the downvotes? This question is mistaken, but is it "unclear or not useful"? True, it doesn't show research effort, but it implies that some (misguided or misunderstood) has happened. I encourage other users to remember that downvotes don't mean "I don't like this," but "If you're only going to answer a few questions, don't bother with this one."

You are confusing two usages of the future continuous.
There is a "planned activity" use of the future continuous:

What activities are you planning for your daughter's birthday party this weekend?
-- Oh, nothing extravagant. We'll be playing pin-the-tail-on-the-donkey, musical chairs, and perhaps some skeet shooting, but only if the parents are willing to sign the necessary liability releases. Ha ha. Just kidding. No skeet-shooting.

And there is also the "to be actively engaged in an activity" usage:

Everybody, if you're going to chat the morning away, come over to this easel and stare at this productivity chart while you're gossiping, so if the boss happens to walk in, we will be doing something work-related.

Your sentence

When she comes we will be playing games.

could be an instance of the actively-engaged-in-an-activity usage. But it doesn't work as an instance of the planned-activity usage.  If you want to say what you plan to do after she arrives, you don't use the continuous:

When she arrives, we will play some games.

The reason is that "when she arrives" establishes a coincident point-in-time in the future but a plan is a future projection originating in the present. A point-in-time cannot coincide with a mere intention.
